# Implementing a Google-test matcher for a hierarchical object

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

I'd like to implement a gtest matcher for a struct, simplified to:

```cpp
struct Element {
  enum class Type { String, Vector };
  using Vec = std::vector<Element>;

  Type GetType() const { return Type::Vector; }
  std::string GetString() const { return "..."; }
  Vec GetVec() const { return {}; }
};
```

In my tests, I'd like to use that matcher to, for example, verify that it contains specific elements. Ideally, I'd like in the future to specify a hierarchical statement, but I can't even get a simple version to compile.

I've tried:

```cpp
template <typename ValueMatcher> class ElementArrayMatcher {
 public:
  explicit ElementArrayMatcher(ValueMatcher value_matcher) : value_matcher_(value_matcher) {
  }

  operator testing::Matcher<Element>() const {
    return testing::Matcher<Element>(new Impl(value_matcher_));
  }

  class Impl : public testing::MatcherInterface<const Element&> {
   public:
    using ElementVec = Element::Vec;

    explicit Impl(const ValueMatcher& value_matcher)
        : value_matcher_(MatcherCast<ElementVec>(value_matcher)) {
    }

    bool MatchAndExplain(const Element& x,
                         testing::MatchResultListener* listener) const override {
      if (x.GetType() != Element::Type::Vector) {
        *listener << " Element is not an array, it is of type " << x.GetType();
        return false;
      }

      return value_matcher_.MatchAndExplain(x.GetVec(), listener);
    }

    void DescribeTo(::std::ostream* os) const override {
      value_matcher_.DescribeTo(os);
    }

    void DescribeNegationTo(::std::ostream* os) const override {
      value_matcher_.DescribeNegationTo(os);
    }

   private:
    const testing::Matcher<ElementVec> value_matcher_;
  };

 private:
  const ValueMatcher value_matcher_;
};

template <typename InnerMatcher>
ElementArrayMatcher<InnerMatcher> ElementArray(const InnerMatcher& inner_matcher) {
  return ElementArrayMatcher<InnerMatcher>(inner_matcher);
}

TEST(Test, Test) {
  Element e;
  ;;;
  EXPECT_THAT(e, ElementArray(testing::ElementsAre()));
}
```

But it fails to compile because, for some reason, it tries to compare `Element` with `ElementArrayMatcher`:

```
build-dbg/_deps/gtest-src/googletest/include/gtest/gtest-matchers.h:179:60: error: no match for _operator==_ (operand types are _const Element_ and _const ElementArrayMatcher<testing::internal::ElementsAreMatcher<std::tuple<> > >_)
  179 |   bool operator()(const A& a, const B& b) const { return a == b; }
```

What am I doing wrong? I've tried to basically copy `testing::Optional`, and looked at many other matchers and couldn't find the issue.

Comment: Is this correct reproduction link https://godbolt.org/z/jGhEjd49P ? I see error is different.

Comment: It looks close enough, perhaps I'm using a different version.

Comment: BTW In such cases I usually relay on macro which makes this task much simpler: https://godbolt.org/z/YsYbj79qx

Comment: Wow, nice! Will that allow to call in a nested way, like `ElementArray(ElementsAre(ElementsArray(...)))` ?

Comment: Yes as you can see in demo.